# Show submenu's submenu on submenu hover only

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to show the submenu on hovering the menus. I have succeeded in submenu level 1. But when I go to submenu level 2(ie, submenu of submenu) it is not working. I want to show the level 2 submenu only on hovering the level 1 submenu. Following is the code that I have tried

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Capabilities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Approach</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Careers</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Working With Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work Culture</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Following is the jQuery

```
$('ul.submenu').hide();
$('ul.nav > li').hover(function () {
if ($(this).find('ul.submenu').length > 0) {
    $(this).find('ul.submenu').stop().slideDown('slow');
}
},function () {
    if ($(this).find('ul.submenu').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('ul.submenu').stop().slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

Please find the Fiddle Here : http://jsfiddle.net/Midhun28/RbY83/1/

Comment: If its any help I know CSS method would be ul li ul li:hover ul {display:block}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as far as i understood you want to slidedown the submenu on hovering the list item one level above

```
<ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">Working With Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work Culture</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

i added the submenu class to all elements i want them to be initially hidden. then i made some modifications on the jquery code to work with all submenus

```
$('ul.submenu').hide();
$('ul.nav > li, ul.submenu > li').hover(function () {
if ($('> ul.submenu',this).length > 0) {
    $('> ul.submenu',this).stop().slideDown('slow');
}
},function () {
    if ($('> ul.submenu',this).length > 0) {
        $('> ul.submenu',this).stop().slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

hope this will work for you
see http://jsfiddle.net/U7mqM/

Answer (score 3):

Use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events if you want them to be triggered when you hover on the sub-elements.

```
$('.nav ul').hide();

$('.nav li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown('slow')
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp('slow')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
            topNav = jQuery('ul.topnav > li > a');
            if(jQuery(topNav).hasClass('hover')){
                        return
            }
            jQuery(topNav).hover(function(){
                    jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
                    jQuery(this).next('.subnav').slideToggle('', function(){                        
                        jQuery(topNav).removeClass('hover');
                });
            });
        });
```