# Find object in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, arrayobject

I have been spinning my wheels on this for a while now.  I have an object array constructed like this :

```
0: {name: "Coaches", isActive: true, locations: Array(13)}
1: {name: "Directors", isActive: false, locations: Array(13)}
2: {name: "Trainers", isActive: false, locations: Array(5)}
```

I have a nav menu and when mouse enters gets the text of the line item.  Now I am trying to in my array compare that text to the name text so i can build the sub items of locations

```
        $('.nav ul').hide();
    $('.nav li').mouseenter(function () {                        
        $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown('slow');
        var text = $(this).find('span').text();
        //console.log(text);

        var item = leftNavData.modules.findIndex(i => i.name.toLowerCase() === "coaches");
        var i = leftNavData.modules.find(x => x.name.toLowerCase() == text.toLowerCase());
        console.log(i);
        console.log(item);

    }).mouseleave(function () {

        $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp('slow')
    });
```

The find always returns the same object the first one coaches even if I mouse over other elements.

The text is changing but the find always retuns the first object.

The findIndex is always 0.

I've started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176908/how-to-get-index-of-object-by-its-property-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396071/show-submenus-submenu-on-submenu-hover-only)

Any Ideas or something that I have missed?

Thanks

Comment: `.toLowerCase()` is a method, not a property.

Comment: You are not calling `toLowerCase`. It lacks parentheses: `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: yea i didnt see that at all but either way now its undefined and -1 still not finding the item

Comment: Please update your question with a snippet we can run and reproduce the problem with.

Comment: `"coaches"` and `"Coaches"` are not the same string.

Comment: You didn't fix all `toLowerCase`...

Answer (score 1):

Simple error based on the misunderstanding that `.toLowerCase()` is a method, not a property.

```
.toLowerCase()
```

not

```
.toLowerCase
```

Comment: yea i didnt see that at all but either way now its undefined and -1 still not finding the item

Comment: even though updated still returns the first item in the array no matter what?